# ng2-daterangepicker to set minDate with selected startDate

Tags: angular, daterangepicker

My html goes with Start Date and End Date. End Date value must be selected with start date as the starting date for end date.

```
<div class="input-group" [options]="singlePicker" (selected)="selectStartDate($event)" daterangepicker>
    <span class="form-control uneditable-input" name="start">
        {{ startDate | date: 'M/dd/y' }}
    </span>
</div>
<div class="input-group" [options]="singleEndPicker"
(selected)="selectEndDate($event)" daterangepicker>
    <span class="form-control uneditable-input" name="start">
        {{ endDate | date: 'M/dd/y' }}
    </span>
</div>
```

Component goes with separate options for both the date pickers.

```
/* Option for startDate*/
public singlePicker = {
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    opens: "left"
}
/* Option for endDate*/
public singleEndPicker = {    
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    opens: "left",
    minDate: moment().local().format('MM/DD/YYYY') // need to set the startDate here
 }
```

How can I set minDate option as selected startDate value?

Answer (score 0):

The current version now supports change detections and you should be able to update the minDate after every selection by just updating it